# SQL - Remove Duplicate Rows From Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I remove duplicate rows from my table? I've searched the Internet, but I haven't been able to solve the issue. Here's what I've written:

```
WITH C As
(
Select A.PatientID, A.DoctorID
From Appointment As A
)

Select Distinct A.PatientID, A2.PatientID, A.DoctorID
From Appointment As A
    Inner Join C as A2
        On A.DoctorID = A2.DoctorID
Where A.PatientID <> A2.PatientID
Order By A.PatientID Asc
```

Here's the outcome:

[image: Duplicate Data]

In the image above, you'll notice that the data in row 1 is duplicated in row 6. How can I remove all the duplicate rows? Any suggestions?

Comment: You want delete? or remove it from a select? what is your rdbms?

Comment: I want to remove it from the select statement.

Comment: postgres, oracle or sql server? How is you have two field name PatientID ?

Comment: Sql server... The PatientID fields are the same columns. I'm comparing them against themselves.

Comment: I'm trying to show two pairs of patients who have the same doctor.

Comment: ohh then is easy ... change `A.PatientID <> A2.PatientID` for `A.PatientID < A2.PatientID`

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much! If you write up an answer, I'll mark you as the  answer.

Comment: Just a tip to improve your next question. Usually the question are This is what I have (db structure + sample data) This is query I have ( with sample result) This is my desire result. You went backwards so was a litle confuse.

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: In real life, can patient A have two appointments with Dr B on different days?  If so, how does that effect what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DanBracuk I think the `DISTINCT` solve that issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need a CTE for this

Try

```
 SELECT DISTINCT PatientId, PatientId, DoctorID
 FROM Appointment A1
 JOIN Appointment A2
   ON A1.PatientId < A2.PatientId
  AND A1.DoctorID = A2.DoctorID
 Order By A1.PatientID Asc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not generate the symmetric dups 
in the first place by arbitrarily choosing patient A to allways be the one of the pair with the smaller ID

```
...
Where A.PatientID < A2.PatientID
```

This will not help if you have dups in the original table but by its name it should be a primary key and/or have a not NULL & unique index on "PatientID"